# How to install bundler gem on Hetzner server?

Tags: debian, ruby-on-rails, bundler

I am trying to install bundler using the following command:

```
gem install bundler
```

but recieve this error:

```
ERROR:  could not find gem bundler locally or in a repository
```

Running command

```
gem list --local
```

shows me empty list and

```
gem sources
```

shows this:

```
http://gems.rubyforge.org/
http://rubygems.org/
http://gemcutter.org
```

I was trying to find the similar problem for an hour, but seems to me that I am not understanding some basic principles to make correct google search query.

Answer (score 0):

What Linux distribution are you using? How is Ruby packaged, is it a package from a distribution repo? Basically I recommend you to try [RVM](http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/), it is a popular and a convenient way to manage Ruby setups in a distribution-agnostic way. I always use RVM and never have problems like this.

Comment: Ruby was installed from ISPManager, linux is Debian 2.6.26-24